# can a dlopened module call a function in the caller?

Tags: c, dlopen

say I have a parent and a child, the child calls a function "hello" in the child with dlopen. Can the child then call a function "world" in the parent? I keep getting symbol lookup error: ./child.so: undefined symbol: world

here are the files. parent.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
typedef void (*fptr)();
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
 void*handle=dlopen("./child.so",RTLD_LAZY);
 fptr f=dlsym(handle,"hello");
 f();
 return 0;
}

void world() {
 printf ("world");
}
```

and child.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello () {
 printf ("hello");
 world();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it a `dlopen`-ed module can call functions from the calling program, provided that the calling program has been linked with the `-rdynamic` option.

BTW, most plugins need that feature: a firefox plugin obviously wants to call firefox functions.

Read also about [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) function [`__attribute__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) ... Read also [Drepper's How to Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) long paper and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) man page.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on google

http://www.justskins.com/forums/dlopen-calling-functions-other-104185.html

gcc -rdynamic hello.c -ldl

Comment: tovarish Starynkevitch beat me by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly it can. I've personally seen it happen.

You may need to link to the executable with `-rdynamic`